# Local dom manipulation, and styling for form validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to press submit on the form, if there is nothing in the input field, or it doesn't meet the email parameters, it should pop up with the little error image next to the input field. All local dom manipulation. Using HTML CSS and JS. Keep getting error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
at HTMLButtonElement.

```js
"use strict"

const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
const errorImg = document.querySelectorAll(".error-img");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");


submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!inputs.value){
        errorImg.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        errorImg.classList.add("hidden");
    }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap);

body{
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    margin: 6rem auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 70%;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "left right"
    "left right";
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 32rem);
}

.left-container{
    grid-area: left;
}

.left-heading{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-weight: 700;

    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
}

.left-content{
    color: white;
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-weight: 400;

    position: relative;
    top: 29%;
}

.right-container{
    grid-area: right;
}

.right-top-container{
    background-color: hsl(248, 32%, 49%);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    height: 11.5%;
    margin: auto auto 1.5rem auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.top-text-special{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: .85rem;

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 72%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.top-text{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.right-form{
    background-color: white;
    height: 23rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "fname"
    "lname"
    "email"
    "password"
    "submit-btn"
    "bottom-text";
}

input{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: .8rem;

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0 0 0 1.5rem;

    height: 130%;
    width: 90%;

    border: solid;
    border-width: .09rem;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    border-color: hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
}

.first-name-div{
    grid-area: fname;
    margin: 0 0 7% 0;

    position: relative;
}

.last-name-div{
    grid-area: lname;
    margin: 0 0 7% 0;

    position: relative;
}

.email-div{
    grid-area: email;
    margin: 0 0 7% 0;

    position: relative;
}

.password-div{
    grid-area: password;
    margin: 0 0 7% 0;

    position: relative;
}

.submit-btn-div{
    grid-area: submit-btn;
}

#submit-btn{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 97.1%;
    height: 130%;
    border-radius: .4rem;

    background-color: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

    cursor: pointer;
}

.right-footer-text{
    grid-area: bottom-text;
}

.footer-text{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 58%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    color: grey;
    font-size: .7rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.footer-span{
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
}

#error-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 22px;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FrontEndMentor#3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-container">
            <h1 class="left-heading">Learn to code by <br>
                 watching others</h1>
            <p class="left-content">See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. <br>
                Watching scripted tutorials is great, but understanding how <br>
                developers think is invaluable.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="right-top-container">
                <p class="top-text-special">Try it free 7 days <span class="top-text">then $20/mo. thereafter</span></p>
            </div>
            <form action="#" class="form">
            <div class="right-form">
                <div class="first-name-div">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="first-input" placeholder="First Name">
                    <img class="error-img hidden" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="last-name-div">
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="last-input" placeholder="Last Name">
                    <img class="error-img hidden" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="email-div">
                    <input type="email" name="email-address" id="email" placeholder="example@email.com">
                    <img class="error-img hidden" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="password-div">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <img class="error-img hidden" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="submit-btn-div">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</button>
                </div>
            </form>
                <div class="right-footer-text">
                    <p class="footer-text">By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <span class="footer-span">Terms and Services</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't update the classList of a _node list_ which is what `errorImg` is because you're using `querySelectorAll`. You should use [client-side validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) - add a `required` attribute to those inputs and if they're not filled out correctly the browser will show a little pop-up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns an array. An array has no attribute named classList, because array is not an html node, errorImage[0] is the object which has classList attribute.

When u type errorImage.classList.remove, classList is undefined on array, and when you try to access any property of undefined it will return the error that you are facing because undefined is not an object. It is a primitive data type

You can use

```js
const errImgs = document.querySelectorAll(".error-img");

errImgs.forEach(errImg =>
 errImg.classList.remove("hidden")
);
```

This will remove the specific class from all images